# Losing images after loading and saving a workbook in openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x

from openpyxl import load_workbook

input_file = "input.xlsx"
output_file = "output.xlsx"

wb = load_workbook(input_file)
wb.save(output_file)

My input file contains some image file. But while loading it and saving it again all the images are lost from my excel workbook.  Please resolve this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem until I installed the library Pillow.
Check it out: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html

either add it to your requirements.txt or install it using the command

```
pip install Pillow>=8.3.2
```

Hope that helped ^^

Answer (score -1):

As of now, openpyxl does not read all elements present in a Excel file. (See official openpyxl docs: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html)

Essentially, your images aren't showing up because openpyxl doesn't know how to read images.

Try using an alternative library like XlsxWriter (PyPi Page: https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/)

Hope this answer helps!

Happy Coding ~

Comment: XlsxWriter does not read all elements in an Excel file either. In fact it reads nothing from an Excel file since it is a module for creating Excel files only. It cannot and does not open and read existing Excel files.