# openpyxl just deleting random elements in workbook

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

``
openpyxl deleting some of elements in a worksheet im not even editing.

here's how it looks after i saved the file.
[image]

here's how it should look.
[image]

i open the xlsm file using keep_vba and keep_links params true.
if you need any more information just ask.

heres the code that opens and saves the file.

```
    def LoadExccelFile(Code = int):
        wb = ""
        PFileName = "p " + i + ".xlsm"
        DFileName = "d " + i + ".xlsm"
        if os.path.exists(WorksheetFolderPath / i / PFileName):
            wb = load_workbook(WorksheetFolderPath / i / PFileName, keep_vba=True, keep_links=True, data_only=False)
        elif os.path.exists(WorksheetFolderPath / i / DFileName):
            wb = load_workbook(WorksheetFolderPath / i / DFileName, keep_vba=True, keep_links=True, data_only=False)
        else :
            return None
        return wb


    def SaveExccelFile(Code, wb):
        PFileName = "p " + Code + ".xlsm"
        DFileName = "d " + Code + ".xlsm"
        if os.path.exists(WorksheetFolderPath / i / PFileName):
            wb.save(WorksheetFolderPath / i / "Modified.xlsm")
        elif os.path.exists(WorksheetFolderPath / i /DFileName):
            wb.save(WorksheetFolderPath / i / "Modified.xlsm")
        else :
            textFile = open(WorksheetFolderPath / i / "WorksheetMissing.txt" , "w")
            textFile.write("Worksheet Does not Exists")
            return None
```

and when i run this piece of code alone the elements disappear. so the root of problem is here.

Comment: Is the element that's missing part of the vba code in the excel file? In the openpyxl documentation it states *keep_vba (bool) – preseve vba content (this does NOT mean you can use it)* , perhaps that's what's causing it to not show up? keep_links is True by default btw.

Comment: @Notus_Panda no. some shapes, some text boxes, and one pie chart and a few images. the text boxes that have a value in another datasheet remain.

Comment: "Warning

openpyxl does currently not read all possible items in an Excel file so images and charts will be lost from existing files if they are opened and saved with the same name."
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html
This answer speaks about a "fix" (for images, not sure if it'll work for other issues)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70459751/19353309

Comment: @Notus_Panda the images worked but the shapes didn't.